# Datetime SQL selection error

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I'm trying to use python to query a sql database, and then select queries using a datetime (in this case, any entries within the last 5 minutes). I'm getting a weird syntax error, and can't figure out why the syntax is wrong. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477497/programmingerror-syntax-error-at-or-near-when-executing-query-in-python-using) was close, but still doesn't help solve the issue.

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "file.py", line 20, in <module>
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DATA where timestamp between {} and {};".format(fiveMinutesAgo, currentTimestamp))
    psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "13"
    LINE 1: ...M DATA where timestamp between 2017-03-18 13:04:31.1...
                                                         ^
```

Code:

```
    import psycopg2
    import datetime

    conn = psycopg2.connect(#database credentials)

    cur = conn.cursor()


    currentTimestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    fiveMinutesAgo = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DATA where timestamp between {} and {};".format(fiveMinutesAgo, currentTimestamp))

    for record in cur:
        print(record)
```

Printing 10 entries of the timestamp row of the database:

```
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 41, 8, 727398),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 41, 12, 888281),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 42, 5, 139231),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 42, 8, 536972),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 42, 11, 633446),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 43, 7, 425955),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 43, 12, 364544),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 43, 17, 623814),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 44, 4, 142015),)
    (datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 2, 10, 44, 7, 719680),)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use `format` to inject values into SQL-Statements. Use placeholders:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM DATA where timestamp between %s and %s", (fiveMinutesAgo, currentTimestamp))
```